# C++ runtime error

Tags: arcgis-9.3, saex

[image]

I have tried reinstalling the visual c++ from the support folder in ArcGIS installation but still, this error occurs. How can this error be solved?

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.  What were the detailed steps that you performed leading up to seeing this error?

Comment: You have this question tagged with ArcGIS 9.3, which is ancient software, incompatible with modern OS and compilers. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact ArcGIS version,  the Windows version,  an the exact compiler release.

Comment: delete normal.mxt from %appdata%\ESRI\ArcMap\Templates\Normal.mxt